# Cauchy Criteria for Series

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

We know that the Cauchy Criterion of a series is as follow:

**Theorem**: *A series $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{\infty}x_i$ converges iff for all $\epsilon>0$ there is an $N\in \mathbb{N}$ so that for all $n> m > N$ we have $|\sum\limits_{i=m}^{n} x_i|< \epsilon$.*

The proof follows from the fact that "A sequence is convergent if and only if it is Cauchy".

So $(s_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence, where $s_n=\sum\limits_{i=1}^n x_i$. From the definition of Cauchy sequence, given $\epsilon>0$, there exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n > m > N$, $|s_n - s_m|< \epsilon$.

I think it should be  $|s_n- s_m|=|\sum\limits_{i=m+1}^{n} x_i|< \epsilon$ how could we write $|s_n- s_m|=|\sum\limits_{i=m}^{n} x_i|< \epsilon$ ? Are these same things ? What is the point that I missed?

Comment: I agree, the Cauchy criterion for the partial sums gives what you said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statements

(i) *A series $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{\infty}x_i$ converges iff for all $\epsilon>0$ there is an $N\in \mathbb{N}$ so that for all $n> m > N$ we have $|\sum\limits_{i=m}^{n} x_i|< \epsilon$.*

and

(ii) 
*A series $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{\infty}x_i$ converges iff for all $\epsilon>0$ there is an $N\in \mathbb{N}$ so that for all $n> m > N$ we have $|\sum\limits_{i=m+1}^{n} x_i|< \epsilon$.*

are equivalent. Indeed, we have the inequalities 
$$\left|\sum\limits_{i=m}^{n} x_i\right|-|x_m|\leqslant \left|\sum\limits_{i=m+1}^{n} x_i\right|\leqslant \left|\sum\limits_{i=m}^{n} x_i\right|+|x_m|,$$
and the conditions of the theorems (i) and (ii) imply that $x_m\to 0$. For (ii), take $n=m+1$ and for (i), we have 
$$|x_m|\leqslant |x_m +x_{m+1} +x_{m+2}|+|x_{m+1}+x_{m+2}|,$$
and these two terms converge to $0$.